# Covering 2011 by 2011 chessboard with 52 by 52 tiles

Tags: combinatorics

I want to cover a 2011 by 2011 chessboard with 52 by 52 square tiles, so that all square of the chessboard are covered. For every square, one can count the number of tiles that covers that square, and assign that number to that square. The goal is to find the maximum number of squares $k$ that has the same number assigned among every possible covering.

Since $2011=52\times39-17$, I first assumed that the maximum number $k$ would be $(2011-17)^2$, but it does not seem to be the optimal.

Comment: This problem was suggested for the 2011 International Mathematical Olympiad. It can be found as problem C7 here: http://imo-official.org/problems/IMO2011SL.pdf.